# Bluetooth Pairing rejects during attempt to programmatically connect BT in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, headphones

I am trying to connect the Bluetooth device (BT headphone) programmatically with my android app. The issue I am facing is in for first couple of attempts it fails to connect the device and says "Pairing Rejected". then after it connects successfully.

Here's my code:

```
package rockwellcollins.bluetooth_pairing_siu;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public BluetoothA2dp btA2dp;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothSocket mSocket = null;
    private UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    public InetAddress serverAddr,serverAddrConnected;
    public Socket socket,socketConnected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        mBluetoothAdapter   = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
                Log.i("oncreate","Bluetooth Service connected.\n");
                btA2dp = (BluetoothA2dp) proxy;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
                Log.i("oncreate", "Bluetooth Service disconnected.\n");
            }
        }, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);

        Log.i("oncreate", "going to start thread.\n");
        Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        fst.start();
        registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));
    }

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable
    {
        String[] strLine;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4500);
                while(true) {
                    Log.i("inrun","in run method");
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    String line = in.readLine();

                    strLine = line.split(";");
                    Log.i("ServerThread", "Line is: " + strLine[1]);
                    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(strLine[1]);
                    if(strLine[0].contains("connect")) {
                        pairDevice(device);
                    }
                    else if(strLine[0].contains("unpair"))
                    {
                        Log.i("run","Going to unpair device");
                        unpairDevice(device, strLine[2]);

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {

        try {
            if(device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
                Log.d("pairdevice", String.valueOf(device.getBondState()));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class FinalThread implements Runnable{

        String strMsg = "";
        public FinalThread(String msg)
        {
            strMsg = msg;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.240.8.23");
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr,5500);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                out.println(strMsg);
                out.flush();
                socket.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device, String seatInfo) {
        try {
            if(device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            }
            Thread sThread = new Thread(new ConnectThread(seatInfo));
            sThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ConnectThread implements Runnable{
        String strSeat = "";
        public ConnectThread(String seat){
            strSeat = seat;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Log.i("ConnectThread","Going to connect");
                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.240.8.23");
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr,5500);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                out.println("startpairconnect;" + strSeat);
                out.flush();
                socket.close();
                Log.i("ConnectThread","Send message back for connect");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            BluetoothDevice deviceBT = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                final int state         = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                final int prevState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    ShowToast("Paired");
                    connectA2dp(deviceBT);
                } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                    ShowToast("Unpaired");
                } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING){
                    ShowToast("Pairing rejected, trying again");
                    pairDevice(deviceBT);
                }

            }
        }
    };
    private void connectA2dp(final BluetoothDevice btdevice) {
        Method connect;
        String strMessage = "";
        try {
            connect = BluetoothA2dp.class.getDeclaredMethod("connect", BluetoothDevice.class);
            //Log.i("connecta2dp","get connect method " + connect);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            Log.e("connectA2dp", "Unable to find connect(BluetoothDevice) method in BluetoothA2dp proxy.");

            return;
        }
        connect.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            //Log.i("connecta2dp","before invoke" );
            connect.invoke(btA2dp, btdevice);
            if(btdevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
                strMessage = "success;" + btdevice.getAddress();
            else
                strMessage = "failure";

            Thread fThread = new Thread(new FinalThread(strMessage));
            fThread.start();
            //Log.i("connecta2dp", "after invoke");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Log.e("connectA2dp", "Unable to invoke connect(BluetoothDevice) method on proxy. " + ex.toString());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Log.e("connectA2dp", "Illegal Access! " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void ShowToast(String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Little explanation of the scenario which rejects the pairing for couple of times class will start a thread on it's onCreate method.Now this thread will continuously monitor the port for a incoming message and once it gets the message it'll extract the mac address of the headphones from it. Once it get the mac address it'll try to connect it programmatically where it fails for couple of attempts and then connects it successfully.

Thanks

Comment: I did one small change in the app, before starting the actual pairing, I did the `mblutoothadapter.startdiscovery()` and when I found the device which I want to connect then only I am doing the pair device. It reduces the pairing rejection error but still I show the error some time. Any idea on this?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue?

Comment: nope. You have the similar issue?

Comment: Yes, and what you need to do is listen for specific error codes from GATT `onCharacteristicRead()`.  So for example, **137** will mean pairing rejected, **133** will mean connection failed, etc.  Often, you just have to retry in a loop.